# i can't figure out how to fix tidymodel error

Tags: r, machine-learning, tidymodels

```
# Partition the data:
library(tidymodels)

set.seed(1234)
uni_split <- initial_split(suspicious_match, strata = truth)
uni_train <- training(uni_split)
uni_test <- testing(uni_split)

uni_split

## Build a model recipe :
library(themis)

uni_rec <- recipe(truth ~ lv + lcs + qgram + jaccard + jw + cosine , data = uni_train)%>%
  step_normalize(all_numeric()) %>%
  step_smote(truth, skip = FALSE)%>%
  prep()

uni_rec

bake(uni_rec, new_data = uni_train)
```

i trained the data with multiple models:(an example)

```
# Train Logistic Regression :
glm_spec <- logistic_reg()%>%
  set_engine("glm")

glm_fit <- glm_spec %>%
  fit(truth ~ lv + lcs + qgram + cosine + jaccard + jw , data= juice(uni_rec))

glm_fit

## Model evaluation with resampling :
set.seed(123)

folds <- vfold_cv(juice(uni_rec), strata = truth)

folds

#1: Logistic Reg:
set.seed(234)

glm_rs <- glm_spec%>%
  fit_resamples(truth ~ lv + lcs + qgram + cosine + jaccard + jw, folds, 
                metrics = metric_set(roc_auc, sens, spec, accuracy),
                control = control_resamples(save_pred = TRUE))

## Evaluation des modeles : 

glm_rs  %>% collect_metrics()

> glm_rs  %>% collect_metrics()
# A tibble: 4 x 6
  .metric  .estimator  mean     n std_err .config             
  <chr>    <chr>      <dbl> <int>   <dbl> <chr>               
1 accuracy binary     0.851    10 0.00514 Preprocessor1_Model1
2 roc_auc  binary     0.898    10 0.00390 Preprocessor1_Model1
3 sens     binary     0.875    10 0.00695 Preprocessor1_Model1
4 spec     binary     0.827    10 0.00700 Preprocessor1_Model1
```

but then when i try applying the logistic regression model to the test data i get this error:

```
> glm_fit %>%
+   predict(new_data = bake(uni_rec, new_data = uni_test),
+           type = "prob")%>%
+   mutate(truth = uni_test$truth)%>%
+   roc_auc(truth, .pred_correct)
Erreur : Problem with `mutate()` input `truth`.
x Input `truth` can't be recycled to size 2022.
i Input `truth` is `uni_test$truth`.
i Input `truth` must be size 2022 or 1, not 1373.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

i figured it's because of the smote step in the recipe but i can't figure out how to fix it
please help !!

Comment: You should keep `skip = TRUE` in step_smote. This makes sure that the step is only applied to the training data set. By setting it to FALSE you are making it upsample when predicting which doesn't make sense since you want the same number of observations throughout prediction

Comment: thanks , i tried your way , that's the way to fix it

Answer (score 0):

When you used `bake`, your test set changed. (@Emil Hvitfeldt identified why.)
I didn't have the data you used, but what I used left the outcome variable (`truth` in your data) alone when `bake` was applied. Therefore, you can drop the call to `mutate`. When I found that worked as expected, I found that `truth` wasn't recognized in the `roc_auc`.

To find these errors I ran

```
fit.p <- gpl_fit %>% predict(new_data = bake(uni_rec, new_data = uni_test),
                             type = "prob")
```

Then I looked at `fit.p`. What worked for my data

```
nd = bake(uni_rec, new_data = uni_test)     

glm_fit %>%
  predict(new_data = nd,
          type = "prob") %>% 
  roc_auc(nd$vs, .pred_0)
```